# Creating array of character pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

Please tell me what's wrong with this code.

Program to input number of students, their names and then print their names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n); // number of students
    char* names[n]; // array of pointers.
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%100[^\n]", names[i]); //student names 
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s", names[i]); // printing students names
    }
}
```

It does not show any error on compiling but it does not work.

Comment: `char *names[n]` is an array of `char *`. It points to nothing (garbage) when you attempt to write a string to it.  You need to allocate `char []` memory for it.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve]. What exactly does "does not work" really mean? [Edit] your post and show some sample inputs/outputs.